# JSX error: Unexpected Token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm running into an unexpected error while writing JSX functional component with NextJS. As soon as I insert a different component in my code, it would return "Unexpected token" error.

I've tried adding {}, (), change to function Entries(){}, move the mockList into the function, but none worked. I'm still receiving this error once I place another component inside the return.

Function component Entries

```
import Entry from './Entry'
import Detail from './Detail'

const mockList = [
    { title: "Subway"},
    { title: "Yokohama"},
    { title: "Tokyo Station"},
    { title: "Shibuya"},
    { title: "Shinjuku"},
]

const Entries = () => {

    return (
            mockList.map(list =>
                <Entry title={list.title} />
                )
            )

}

export default Entries
```

as soon as I changed **Entries** to

```
const Entries = () => {

    return (
            mockList.map(list =>
                <Entry title={list.title} />
                )
            <Detail />
            )

}
```

The error will pop up.

Any suggestion on how to fix this problem? It's been frustrating not to be able to continue with this unexpected error.

I'm writing functional component as a practice to use React Hooks down the road in this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return one top level tag in the component. Also the javascript part has to be between `{}`

```
const Entries = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {mockList.map(list => <Entry title={list.title} />)}
      <Detail />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I was just about to post similar solution. Finally figured out the javascript has to be between {}. Learned a valuable lesson.